# Como deixar o campo para envio de arquivo invisível?

Tags: file-upload, extjs-4

Quero retirar aquela parte "Escolher arquivo.. Nenhum arquivo selecionado" e deixar apenas uma imagem.

Comment: resolveu seu problema?

Answer (score 0):

Achei um jeito simples e interessante de tirar essa parte, ou melhor, esconder.
http://codepen.io/nec/pen/dxfcn
Ele coloca opacity 0 neste input para que fique invisível essa parte.

Comment: aqui sumiu tudo!

Comment: Poderia me mandar um print seu? aqui esta assim:
http://i.imgur.com/1DZp2UF.png

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/BG9IsRr.png?1 Eu quero deixar apenas aquela imagenzinha acima de "Escolher arquivo"

Comment: Cara se bem que isso vai de navegador por navegador, por exemplo, no internet explorer não aparece essa imagem em cima, agora existem maneiras de você pegar a imagem e colocar ela em cima do input, vou trazer um exemplo aqui....

Comment: Veja se é isto que você deseja, teste com alguma imagem sua:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YPEZeG

Comment: O que eu almejo é isso aqui: http://i.imgur.com/Wbblli3.png

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, para estilizar o campo `input[type=file]` eu uso o plugin Jquery Filestyle.
Dá para fazer muita coisa legal com ele.

Mais informações aqui: http://markusslima.github.io/jquery-filestyle/